# Javascript "window.location" stopping PHP redirect

Tags: php, javascript

Basically there's a callto function, and a timer. The timer is displayed visually via Javascript countdown, and at the same time there's a PHP redirect which has been set to the same length as the Javascript countdown. However, the window.location callto function is preventing the PHP header redirect from working. Can anybody tell me why?

The Javascript window.location function (located after body due to it preventing code below it from being processed:

```
<?
echo"
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location='callto:".$to."';
</script>";
?>
```

The PHP header redirect (above the html tag):

```
<?php

header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );

?>
```

If I remove the window.location function the redirect works.

Comment: I think you're confused. Do you want the page to redirect to wherever.php or the callto: ? If both are happening after (say) 5 seconds, then it's a race as to which gets there first; just include the one you want. Also, the example you've given for the javascript "function" isn't a function, it's an immediate redirect. You describe it as being called after a timer has counted down, but in fact it's just an instruction to immediately change location. Which do you want?

Comment: This is for a touch screen reception, where a customer selects a department to call. I'm unsure of the setup of the actual call system, but the window.location='callto:...' does not go to a different page, it simply connects to the call system that creates a call to the selected department. It will stay on the same page. However, this is causing the PHP redirect to not work - the redirect is required to stop it being stuck on the "in-call" screen. I hope this clears it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should redirect just with javascript, don't redirect with php. why doing a php redirect when you're doing it already with javascript?

In order to delay the redirect you should use Javascript setTimetout() function, such as:

```
setTimeout(function () {document.location = 'detination';}, time_in_miliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

This is NOT a valid redirecting header!

```
header('Location: http://example.com/sub/script.php');
```

THIS is a valid Redirect Header!

To make the script wait as you want , you'll need to add a Sleep on it:

```
sleep(5);
header('Location: http://example.com/sub/script.php');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not include the timed aspect of it.

Comment: Yes, because a header redirect is done as soon, as the header arrives at the client - there is no timing whith a header redirect. For timing a redirect, deliver a HTML page with an Meta redirect...

Comment: Yes , your point on the timeout is fair, still you should correct the question as many people might see the question and take that as right

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a javascript redirect you should render an call-link with simple html and the href="callto:...". 
If you want to show the call screen without user interaction you only have to trigger a click event on the link.